# Proper mock function for multiple tests inside component

Tags: reactjs, function, jestjs, mocking, react-testing-library

Unfortunately I couldn't find answer to my question. May be someone can refer me if it's already exists.

I have a problem to use mock function inside React component for multiple tests.
For example component Login contains hook called `useAuthState`, and in my test I mock it like this:

```
jest.mock('../state/useAuthState', () => 
   jest.fn(() => (require('./useAuthStateTest').default as any)()))

const renderLogin = () => {
   const Login = require('../components/Login').default
   return render(<Login />)
}

test('some test 1' () => {
    renderLogin()
})

test('some test 2' () => {
    renderLogin()
})
```

First test `some test 1` executed successfully, but `some test 2` throw error:

> TypeError: (0 , _useAuthState.default) is not a function or its
> return value is not iterable

If I will comment out `some test 1` then `some test 2` will passed. Why I cannot mock function for multiple tests inside the component? What I missed in the documentation?

Comment: Did you try what is described here : https://chanonroy.medium.com/mocking-hooks-for-testing-with-jest-and-react-testing-library-d34505616d12 ? You need a specific mock for custom hooks

Comment: @FlorianMotteau what i see from link you sent I'm using similar implementation and there only one test using in example which is woking fine

Comment: It seems that you need to add a default function in your mock, like for mocking functionnal components with a default export.

Comment: @FlorianMotteau I found the problem, please have a look my answer.

Comment: Great thanks for letting me know ! I never mocked custom hooks, but I spent some time before I could mock functional components with default export with Jest (same principle), still unclear to me...

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue,

instead of using this code:

```
jest.mock('../state/useAuthState', () => 
   jest.fn(() => (require('./useAuthStateTest').default as any)()))
```

need to replace to this one:

```
jest.mock('../state/useAuthState', () => 
     require('./useAuthStateTest').default)
```

And it will work for multiple tests in one file.

To summarise this approach like described in this [tutorial](https://chanonroy.medium.com/mocking-hooks-for-testing-with-jest-and-react-testing-library-d34505616d12) in the Internet doesn't work (to mock function in React component) for multiple tests in one file:

```
jest.mock('something_to_mock', () => 
    jest.fn(() => ...))
```

if we replace to this code:

```
 jest.mock('something_to_mock', () => 
        (() => ...))
```

it will work.

Not sure why. Maybe someone who knows internally reactjs very well may explain.

To replicate this issue u can use this simple test project:

- [SomeComponent.tsx](https://gist.github.com/inspifinity/5f2501536514a61a7d4ea950a08d993f)
- [useFakeState.ts](https://gist.github.com/inspifinity/05758a47f772cd6690d3d764b37b5eb5)
- [TestMockBug.test.tsx](https://gist.github.com/inspifinity/13c7353bb7a1ca111539d4f5a980c0b9)